# Phonegap File API not returning correct path only returns '/'

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera

I have been developing a phonegap+angularjs app and building for android and iphone using phonegap builder. When I use the File API of phonegap, I cant access the app documents folder in IOS and not able to move or copy my file from one location to another based on the documents folder. After taking a picture, I tried to get the fullpath of the image to move it to persistent folder like this

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileURL, function(fileEntry) { 
});
```

But `fileEntry` returns `'/'` only instead of `'file://var/mobile/......'` in iOS.

Is this an issue with phonegap? It was working fine 2 days earlier but not now

Please help

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: I didnt do anything except some changes in javascript. But fileEntry.fullPath was giving the full path as expected earlier but not now

Answer (score 1):

I think phonegap change it to resolveLocalFileSystemURL (instead of ...URI) a few days ago.
From the phonegap update: http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/02/10/plugins-release.html

> CB-5008: Rename resolveLocalFileSystemURI to resolveLocalFileSystemURL

They also change how you get the full URL.

**Before**

```
window.requestFileSystem(
    LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function (fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.fullPath;
    },
    function (evt) {
        console.warn("error");
    }
);
```

**Now**

```
    window.requestFileSystem(
    LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function (fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.toURL();
    },
    function (evt) {
        console.warn("error");
    }
);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Ok.. I'll try that. I am also not getting the device specific details as the build showing 'device' object undefined error

Comment: That is odd, are you sure you include the phonegap.js script and call all this functions when the device is ready?

Comment: Yes.. It was also an issue with phonegap I think since it is working now. But when I used your above code I got filesystem root path as 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent' and when I accessed my file from that url it is not working..